# gradle jetty plugin does not stop when using daemon=true in jettyRun

Tags: java, gradle, embedded-jetty

I'm using the following gradle script for very simple web application:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   providedCompile deps['servlet-api']
   providedCompile deps['commons-io']
   providedCompile deps['gson']
}

jettyRun {
   contextPath = "/"
   httpPort = 8900
   stopPort = 9800
   stopKey = "pleaseStop"
   daemon = true
}

jettyStop {
   stopPort = 9800
   stopKey = "pleaseStop"
}
```

When I run `jettyRun` the app works but when I run `jettyStop` it does not stop.
If I change daemon to false `jettyStop` does stop the embedded Jetty server.

How can I stop the embedded Jetty server when use in daemon mode?

Comment: What do you get when you run jettyStop command in deamon mode true?

Comment: Complete successfully but the jetty URL is still active until I run 'gradle --stop'

Comment: I found this discussion which suggest in daemon mode stop is not relevant. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-run-integration-tests-with-jetty-plugin/5962/5